# filter methods in before_action after of another before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, before-filter

how can I filter a second before_action?, I have two controllers, and when I call the method A, a before_action executes a methodB, but before executing this second method I would like to execute a general methodC, but in this method I need to pass a parameter to know where is coming from, but if I use a second before_action this doesn't work, because "only" in before_action filters using the first method method (which is methodA), what can I do?

```
class FirstController < SecondController
    before_action :methodB

    def methodA
       #some code
    end
end
```

```
class SecondController < ApplicationController
   before_action only: [:methodB] do
       methodC('methodB')
   end

   def methodB
     #some code new
   end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def methodC(method)
       #general method
    end
end
```

This is the structure that I have:
[image]

Comment: If you want to pass state between two different controllers then you need to pass it through the parameters (the query string), the session or save it somewhere like a database or memory based storage. But this question seems very much like a [X & Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual goal that this elaborate callback scheme is supposed to solve?

Comment: I added to the question the structure that for example, controller A, D and E execute methods to call a db, controllerB  and H verify if the user can access to A, D or E controller but each one in a different way, and controllerC has a general method that B and H use.

Comment: You just went even farther in X & Y question territory. In Rails controllers are not aware of each other. All communication is done through HTTP requests which means that your looking at the problem completely wrong. Tell us the real world problem that you're intending to solve instead of wasting time on a solution that will not work.

Comment: okay, the app that I am creating has 2 environments, they are both using the same db, in my example controller A and D belongs to the first environment, and controller E belongs to the second one, so the methods in each environment will grow up. To use each environment we need to login with different users from db, so to access to different methods, I need to validate if the user has access, so I use the controller H or B to define the method there, but they both use a general method to decode a token, so that's in the controller C

Comment: This sounds more like an architecture issue. The only public methods of a controller should be the "actions" which are the methods that respond to HTTP requests. If you have a method that should be used by more then one controller it should not be defined in a controller in the first place - it should be in a module (a concern in Rails lingo) or be handled by a separate object such as a service object.

Comment: This also really sounds like you should look into using Pundit for authorization instead of reinventing the wheel. https://github.com/varvet/pundit

Comment: okay, let me check it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm out of practice with rails but would the following be acceptable?

```rb
class FirstController < SecondController
    before_action :methodB

    def methodA
       #some code
    end

    private

    def should_call_C
      action_name == :methodA
    end
end
    
class SecondController < ApplicationController
   before_action do |controller|
       methodC if controller.should_call_C
   end

   def methodB
     #some code new
   end

   private

   def should_call_C
     action_name == :methodB
   end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def methodC
       #general method
       # can use action name to get method rather than passing it?
    end
end
```

Comment: This is really just a very overcomplicated way of doing `before_action :methodC, only: :methodB`. However I don't really think the question is actually answerable as it has X&Y question written all over it.

Comment: I was really just demonstrating that they can use `action_name` to get the action to be called. Also this should call methodC before calling methodA as well right? In following order methodC -> methodB -> methodA

Comment: No not really. It will call the callback `:methodC` if the action name is `methodB`. If method A is called at all depends entirely on the order if the HTTP requests calling the controllers. Thats what makes the question "broken". I think what the OP might be aiming at is something like a form wizard which can be done by redirecting to form after form but its impossible to tell since the asker is so focused on barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Well the way I interpreted it was, there will be routeA for methodA. When routeA is requested action_name will be methodA. It will enter before action defined in SecondController as it is inherited in FirstController, then call should_call_C and return true thus calling methodC. Then it will run before_action as defined in FirstController which will call methodB. Likewise we will have routeB for methodB when we http request routeB we enter before action and check should_call_C which will also be true.